# Azure Data Sync - specify destination object owner

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-sync

I am setting up a simple data sync, only updated at the Hub database and I want to specify he destination owner for the tables included in this sync group.

Ex: The table dbo.TableName at the Hub database should be notdbo.TableName at the other databases in the sync group

I have not been able to find if this is possible, anyone who knows better than me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Trond, If my answer is helpful for you, pleasen accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The source table and destination table can be different database schema. And the tables schema should better be same.

We can sync the table from `dbo.table1` to `nodbo.table1`. The limit is:

- If there are tables with the same name but different schema (for
  example, dbo.customers and sales.customers) only one of the tables
  can be added into sync.

For more details, you can ref here: [Requirements and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database#sync-req-lim)

HTH.